# Item build not saving in DotA 2

Tags: dota-2

I edit my custom item build/abilities for Riki, and it is marked as "saved", but in-game the standard item build appears.

What's the problem?

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it funny? "Riki item build invisble"

Comment: @RayofCommand : I do not mean only riki, every hero. not saved at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The in-game item/skill build creator is buggy. You should try to use the [web-app](http://www.dota2.com/workshop/builds) for that.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: That's very unfortunate. Do other guides load for you? Or only valve's default guide? If no other guides or no guides at all are shown your issue is another one. Also: did you view the guide menu? Re-reading your original question makes me think that you may not know that you have to activate the guide first.

Comment: Only Valve's default guide load for all heroes.
And how to activate the guide? I am just edit it and save it.

Comment: Here is a dota wiki article which should help you find it: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Head-up_display#Guides Also look for the main UI image on the top of the page. There is a book which you have to click to show the guides.